# How to use Kafka Round robin and load balancing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 kafka cluster and 1 producer and 3 consumers with the same topic.

I want to receive one msg to consumer at a time(it shouldn't receive to all the consumers). Like round robin mode it should work.

same GROUP  - Always only one consumer receiving the msg
different GROUP - all the consumers receiving the msg.

But i want only one consumer receiving the msg at the time. not Always the same consumer. It should be different consumer for each msg.

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can't you create 3 partitions for your topic, with one group of 3 consumers?

Comment: am not getting your question clearly. can u pls explain it details?

Comment: If you create one group that contains three consumers and you also use three partitions for your topic, you would have one consumer assigned to one partition. Every message in a partition will only be read by one and only one of your consumer.

Something like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/d63413571d237bda02da5ef7dd948ca22648311e/687474703a2f2f332e62702e626c6f6773706f742e636f6d2f2d6b766a41634e30764666672f557162346d363348335f492f41414141414141414147772f7a4a37587247646a6944412f73313630302f6b61666b612d636f6e63657074732e706e67).